# Is EmguCV's System.Drawing.Rectangle usage by (Row,Column) or (X,Y)?

Tags: c#, opencv, coordinate-systems, emgucv

For example, in this method:

[`Image.Copy(Rectangle roi)`](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/3.0.0/document/html/2528290c-8802-d51b-116b-79f0bc9acba6.htm)

A new `Image` is returned, cropped according to the `System.Drawing.Rectangle` parameter.  An example usage is:

```
var image = new Image<Gray, Byte>("filename.jpg");
var cropRectangle = new Rectangle(0, 200, 100, 10);
var cropped = image.Copy(cropRectangle);
```

OpenCV, EmguCV, and, hence, the `Image` class all operate with the coordinate system `(Row, Column)`, but `Rectangle` operates with the more conventional `(x, y)` coordinate system.

How do those two coordinate systems map between each other?  Should I create a `Rectangle` with `x == 100` and `y == 10` to crop starting at the 100th row and 10th column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to switch rows and cols.

```
// Crop from row (y) = 20, col (x) = 30, width = 40, height = 50
// Rectangle(x, y, width, height)

var cropRectangle = new Rectangle(30, 20, 40, 50);
```

Comment: Good answer.  Passersby:  look below for a visual depiction.

Answer (score -1):

**The `Rectangle` class will describe a region of interest in the (x,y) coordinate system you are used to.**

For example, the following `Rectangle` region will describe the yellow rectangle from the following image:

```
var bound = new Rectangle(0, 200, 100, 10);

// bound.X == 0
// bound.Y == 200
// bound.Width == 100
// bound.Height == 10
```

[image: Crop coordinate description.]